# How to Specifically Schedule Pipelines with Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, shell, azure-devops

How to schedule a one time run, non-repeating pipeline in AzurDevOps. I want to create this pipeline for our UAT environment, but I don't want to run it manually, so I was thinking is there a way I can put multiple specific dates to run the pipeline?

Comment: [Configure schedules for pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/scheduled-triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, we can't schedule a **non-repeating** pipeline in DevOps because it defines a schedule using [cron syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/scheduled-triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#cron-syntax).
Each Azure Pipelines scheduled trigger cron expression is a space-delimited expression with five entries(Minutes, Hours, Days, Months, Days of week).

If you need to run pipeline at some specific days, as a workaround, please schedule it on your end and call the [Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/queue?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1) to run your pipeline.

There are the detailed steps: https://blog.geralexgr.com/cloud/trigger-azure-devops-build-pipelines-using-rest-api.